# Are the names of the textboxes inside a stack panel global variables?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, naming

I would like to dynamically create a series of StackPanels which include several TextBoxes and TextBlocks. I need to be able to get their values, so do I have to make their names globally unique or just unique within the StackPanel?

Comment: What you actually want is an ItemsControl with the StackPanel in its ItemTemplate. The ItemsSource property would be bound to a collection of data item objects with properties that the TextBlocks and TextBoxes bind to. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to the `TextBoxes` which is added to the `StackPanel` children collection like a normal `TextBox`. But you can get their values by their name like this:

```
private static string GetChildValue(Panel panel, string name)
{
    var children = panel.Children;

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        if (!(child is TextBox))
            continue;

        var textBox = (TextBox)child;
        if (textBox.Name.Equals(name))
            return textBox.Text;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

private static void DoSomething()
{
    var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox { Name = "TextBox1", Text = "TextBox1 Value" });
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox { Name = "TextBox2", Text = "TextBox2 Value" });
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox { Name = "TextBox3", Text = "TextBox3 Value" });
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox { Name = "TextBox4", Text = "TextBox4 Value" });

    var textBox1Value = GetChildValue(stackPanel, "TextBox1");
}
```